# Esper : Group Tick data on Security , Find Max and Min of day. And then perform further Computation

Tags: java, stock, esper

I am unable to solve a certain problem in Esper. I have to check if the current Tick value goes up from yesterday Max Value. Here is the code with returns me max and min of every 24 hr.

```
insert into
DayEnd
select
max(last) as high,
min(last) as low,
security
from
Tick.std:groupwin(security).win:time_batch(1440 minutes) group by security;
```

I have to running it on multiple securities so i have to check it for every security.

Answer (score 1):

A batch window is not the right way for such a large batch window. This is because a batch window retains all events.

Use a context declaration instead. Contexts allow you to frame the lifecycle of the analysis.
An example is below and more examples are in the solution patters.
This example is 2 statements, version 4.10, syntax not checked:

create context Batch24Hour as start @now ends after 24 hours;

context Batch24Hour select max(last) as high, min(last) as low, security from Tick group by security output when terminated;

Comment: Ok i get your point. Its better to user context. But i am still confused that how i will use this "high" value and check if in next day tick goes above this value or not. I have to do this for every security .(I am new with Esper so might requires a bit detail explanation.).